# Mock patch the return value of an inner function that's not returned from the outer function

Tags: python, mocking

I'd like to capture the return value of an inner function without having to explicitly return that return value from the outer function.

So I'd like to do something like this:

```
# bar.py
import foo

def my_fn():
    foo.fn()
```

```
# test.py
from mock import patch
import foo
import bar

@patch("foo.fn")
def test_bar(mock_foo_fn):
    bar.my_fn()
    # assert isinstance(mock_foo_fn.return_value, dict)
```

without having to do this:

```
# bar.py
import foo

def my_fn():
    return foo.fn()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a cleaner solution, using a [`spy`](https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#spy).

> The `mocker.spy` object acts exactly like the original method in all cases, except the spy also tracks function/method calls, return values and exceptions raised.

The spy is provided from the `mocker` fixture of the plugin `pytest-mock`. Usage demo for your example:

```
# test.py
import pytest

import bar

def test_bar(mocker):
    spy = mocker.spy(bar.foo, "fn")
    bar.my_fn()
    spy.assert_called_once_with()
    assert spy.spy_return == {"k": "v"}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be more complicated than necessary, but I think you need to patch `foo.fn` with a callable object that capture the return value of the original function, and not just a `Mock`. Something like

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.rv = self.f(*args, **kwargs)

with patch('foo.fn', new=Wrapper(foo.fn)) as m:
    my_fn()
    assert isinstance(m.rv, dict)
```

(Using something like `with patch('foo.fn', wraps=foo.fn)` is not sufficient, because while that ensures that `foo.fn` itself is called when the mock is called, the mock itself doesn't not capture the resulting return value.)

Comment: Thanks. That introduces `pytest` as a dependency, but not unreasonably.

Comment: (And I couldn't remember the term "spy"; all I could remember was "stub", which isn't exactly what the OP is looking for :) )

Comment: @chepner I thought it's likely that O.P. is already using pytest, because a `def test_bar():`  would not be collected at all by a unittest runner (it is not a method of any `TestCase` subclass).

Comment: @chepner I did ended up going with their solution, but yours not requiring an additional dependency has merit; and I thought, since you gave a solution sooner, you earned the acceptance -- but, if you insist, I'll accept the other answer.

Comment: Always accept the best answer, not just the first OK answer :)